# How to fix group cells in DevExtreme DataGrid

Tags: javascript, datagrid, devextreme

I have a large data grid table with lots of columns and some grouping configured. When I scroll right, the grouping labels are moved out of view. How can I fix these labels? See this screenshot:

[image]

My columns are labeled with `Column A`, `Column B` etc. which are displayed in alphabetical order.

`Column A` and `Column B` are configured to be fixed to the left.

`Column C`, `Column D` and `Column E` are configured to be grouped.

An excerpt of my grid configuration looks like this:

```
{
    dataSource: myData,
    allowColumnReordering: true,
    rowAlternationEnabled: true,
    showColumnLines: true,
    showRowLines: false,
    showBorders: true,
    headerFilter: {
        visible: true
    },
    filterRow: {
        visible: true
    },
    grouping: {
        autoExpand: true
    },
    scrolling: {
        mode: "virtual"
    },
    groupPanel: {
        visible: true
    },
    columns: [
        { caption: "Column A", dataField: "propA", width: 100, fixed: true },
        { caption: "Column B", dataField: "propB", width: 350, fixed: true },
        { caption: "Column C", dataField: "groupA", groupIndex: 0, sortOrder: "asc", sortIndex: 0, width: 180 },
        { caption: "Column D", dataField: "groupB", groupIndex: 1, sortOrder: "asc", sortIndex: 1, width: 180 },
        { caption: "Column E", dataField: "groupC", groupIndex: 2, sortOrder: "asc", sortIndex: 2, width: 180 },
        { caption: "Column F", dataField: "propF", allowFiltering: false, width: 90 },
        { caption: "Column G", dataField: "propG", width: 90 },
        { caption: "Column H", dataField: "propH", width: 90 },
        { caption: "Column I", dataField: "propH", width: 90 },
        ...
    ],
    summary: {
        groupItems: {
            column: "Column I",
            summaryType: "sum",
            showInGroupFooter: false,
            alignByColumn: true
        }
    }
}
```

How can I prevent the labels `Column C: Group A0`, `Column D: Group B0` etc. to be moved out of view?

**Update**

Just added an important thing to the config: it seems that using `groupItems` break it. See this codeped (thank you, @sergey): [codepen](http://codepen.io/MichaelHilus/pen/PmvvNy)

Comment: What DevExtreme version do you use? I can't reproduce the behavior you described in the latest version(17.1.3) - https://codepen.io/anon/pen/RVmOeL I use GoogleChrome.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I use version 16.2.6. Just forked your codepen and was able to reproduce the problem. Seems that using summary items break it: https://codepen.io/MichaelHilus/pen/PmvvNy

Comment: I've found the similar issue in DevExpress Support - https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T371042 Check it out.